# Install .pfx and .cer in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, pfx, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a web site already runing using diferent certificates (.pfx and .cer) for 3rd party integration.

Now i need to move all this to Azure. We are going to use App Service.

How can i install them on Azure?
Can someone provide me a site or documentacion about this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need up upload the certificates to the management portal and then you should be able to access them similar to how you currently are doing it (guessing here).

Here's a link to a walkthrough on how to do that with sample code of using the certificate at the bottom of it: [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).  That article is a little dated, but it should still work the same if you use the old portal.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, export the certificate you have as a .pfx file and follow the steps below:

1. You will have to upload the certificate to the Azure Web App. **This needs to be a PFX file (contains private key)**
   In Azure portal, select the webapp with which you intend to use this certificate.

   - In the Settings, Click SSL certificates
   - Click Upload Certificate
   - Select the .pfx file and specify the password .
   - Click **Upload** to upload the certificate.
   - You should see the uploaded certificate under in the **SSL certificate** blade.
2. Add an app setting named **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate. 
   The certificates will be installed to the Personal certificate store of the ApplicationPool Identity of the worker process, which will make it accessible to your web application.

**NOTE: Root CA certificates cannot be installed.**