# Add a certificate to an Azure WebApp and reference it in code

Tags: azure

I have an web  application on IIS. The asp.net application call external resources and need to send a certificate for authorization. I cannot use the certificate store on Azure in a Web App. How can I store a certificate in Azure and reference it when I make a external call?

Comment: This sounds similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107963/install-pfx-and-cer-in-azure/38111775#38111775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use certificated you first have to upload the certifcate to your webapp. You can do this to go to the setting of your webapp and goto custom domain and SSL. Here you can upload your certificate.

In order to be usable in your application Azure cannot use the certificate store but loads the certificates into memory. You can do this by adding WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with value * or you can do it via PowerShell via:

```
$appSettings = "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" = "*"}
$w = Set-AzureWebsite $siteName -AppSettings $appSettings
```

More info can be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/